# change div css property on hover button which is after the div

Tags: html, css

> hover on button but div does not change its property

change CSS property of div by hovering on another tag(button) which is created after it

```css
.zz {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  float: left;
}

#btn:hover~.zz {
  background: green;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg) translate(100px, 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="zz"> this is div</div>
<button id="btn"> hover me </button>
```

Comment: Like so not possible with CSS. You'll need javascript or change the markup.

Comment: 1. this way i know but i need as i said dear

Answer (score 5):

You need to place the `div` after the button in the DOM for sibling selector. Or, you could use javascript to add a class to the `.zz` div.

```css
.zz {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  float: left;
}

#btn:hover ~ .zz {
  background: green;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg) translate(100px, 20px);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn"> hover me </button>
<div class="zz"> this is div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#btn:hover ~ .zz, Selects every `.zz` class that are preceded by a `#btn` id when `#btn` is hover,but in your case `#btn` is before of `.zz`,so `.zz` is not selected.

**So,Just Change :**

```
<div class="zz"> this is div</div>    ---
<button id="btn"> hover me </button>     |
                            Here   <-----
```

**To:**

```
<button id="btn"> hover me </button>
<div class="zz"> this is div</div>
```

```css
.zz{ text-align:center; 
  line-height:100px; 
  font-size:20px; 
  font-weight:bold; 
  width:100px; height:100px; 
  color:white; 
  background:red; 
  border:4px solid black;
   margin:100px;
   
-webkit-transition: transform 1s ;
-webkit-transition-timing:ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition-delay:0.1s;
  float:left;
    }
    
    #btn:hover ~.zz{ background:green;
                -webkit-transform:rotate(40deg) translate(100px,20px);
                
                
            }
```

```html
<button id="btn"> hover me </button>
<div class="zz"> this is div</div>
```